# ImGuizmo, rendered widget but it won;t respond

Tags: c++, graphics, vulkan, imgui, imguizmo

I am trying to integrate imguizmo into a project. I am able to render the guizmo like this:

[image]

However when I hover over the arrows, they don;t get highlighted and I don't get any type of response, I have tried all the methods listed in the readme such as `IsOver` and `IsUsing` which always return false regardless of the position of the cursor. I am also printing the values of the matrix passed into `Manipulate`, it never changes (it;s always the identity matrix).

This is my imgui call:

```cpp
bool show_demo_window = true;
bool show_another_window = false;
ImVec4 clear_color = ImVec4(0.45f, 0.55f, 0.60f, 1.00f);
int selected_vertex = 0;
bool hovering_imgui = false;
static ImGuiWindowFlags gizmoWindowFlags = 0;
static ImGuizmo::MODE mCurrentGizmoMode(ImGuizmo::LOCAL);
static ImGuizmo::OPERATION mCurrentGizmoOperation(ImGuizmo::TRANSLATE);
static bool useSnap = true;
static float snap[3] = { 1.f, 1.f, 1.f };
static float bounds[] = { -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f };
static float boundsSnap[] = { 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f };
static bool boundSizing = false;
static bool boundSizingSnap = false;
float camDistance = 8.f;
Eigen::Matrix4f model = Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity();
void Demo_GUI(NECamera::ArcballCamera& camera)
{
    mCurrentGizmoOperation = ImGuizmo::TRANSLATE;
    // Start the Dear ImGui frame
    ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame();
    ImGui::NewFrame();
    ImGuizmo::BeginFrame();

    ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO();
    float viewManipulateRight = io.DisplaySize.x;
    float viewManipulateTop = 0;
    static ImGuiWindowFlags gizmoWindowFlags = 0;
    
    ImGuizmo::SetRect(0, 0, io.DisplaySize.x, io.DisplaySize.y);

    Eigen::Matrix4f view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
    Eigen::Matrix4f proj = camera.GetProjectionMatrix();
    proj(1, 1) *= -1;

    ImGuizmo::Enable(true);
    ImGuizmo::Manipulate(view.data(), proj.data(), mCurrentGizmoOperation, mCurrentGizmoMode, model.data(), NULL, useSnap ? &snap[0] : NULL, boundSizing ? bounds : NULL, boundSizingSnap ? boundsSnap : NULL);
    ImGui::InputFloat3("Snap", &snap[0]);

    std::cout << model << std::endl;

    // Rendering
    ImGui::Render();
}
```

Imgui itself works, the debug window in the screenshot behaves normally, I can drag it and resize it. So Imgui has been properly configured it;s just ImGuizmo that behaves oddly.

I am not sure what I am missing. Why is the guizmo not responding?

I am using vulkan as the rendering backend.